# Azure Function v2 TypeLoadException ExecutionContext

Tags: azure, azure-functions

**Update: It turned out the Azure DevOps release wasn't correctly deploying the app, so my code changes weren't actually being deployed to Azure. Sigh... I fixed the release and now my function is running fine as v2. So it appears you can convert an existing v1 function to v2 just fine.**

Getting this exception on my v2 function:

Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

As suggested here I updated my nuget packages:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3363

I'm on latest (as of 10/24/18) for:

- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.23
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 3.0.1

But still getting the error. FWIW, this is a converted v1 Function. I have FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION set to ~2 in app settings and version set to 2.0 in host.json.

Comment: Have you tried put your code in a new v2 function template?

Comment: @JerryLiu Not yet, but I updated the .csproj from a new v2 function template's .csproj

Comment: Have you tried recreating you function app? I don't think it's possible to change the major runtime version for an existing app, even by declaring it in the app settings. You can confirm which version is running by looking in the Function app settings (not Application settings).